How to replace symbols of one keyboard layout with similar symbols of another layout and vice versa?(e.g. руддщ => hello)
I need to replace symbols of one keyboard layout to similar symbols of another layout. For example, I forgot to switch the keyboard layout from Russian to English and accidentally wrote руддщ instead of hello. How can I replace characters using c#?

Punto Switcher did that in old good times. I guess it simply monitors for entered text, try convert it to another layout and check dictionary if such word exists and then replaces text somehow (by sending X backspaces and corrected text via SendKeys), as weell as auto-switching layout.

@Sinatr thank you. I din't know about Punto Switcher. You said "_ did that in old good times_". Is Punto Switcher outdated? Why?

It's just grumpy old man in me remembering the 2000s. That utility is old, but not dead I think and there are alternatives.
